# sort 3d vector based on one row (c++, std::sort)

Tags: c++, stdvector

i want to sort a 3d vector, e.g.

```
3 2 1 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```

by one row. The result when to be sorted based on the first row should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 2 1 4 5
3 4 5 2 1
```

I think that is very easy by using the right compare function in std::sort, but how?

Thanks!

Comment: [Any code available from your side?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) We won't provide code out of the blue for you! (And BTW which robo-upvoter idiot put an upvote on this poor question??) For the OP: Show what are your experiments using [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and isn't covered by the examples shown in the reference.

Comment: Btw, it is not a 3d vector.

Comment: I don't understand what you are sorting by.

Comment: The first row is sorted by < operator.
The second and third row are sorted by the same mapping as the first row

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myvect = 
     { { 3, 2, 1 } 
     , { 1, 2, 3 }
     , { 5, 4, 3 }
     , { 0, 1, 3 }
     , { 7, 2, 5 }
     };

std::sort(myvect.begin(), myvect.end(), [](const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b) {
        return a.front()<b.front(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
3 2 1 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```

doesn't make up a 3d, but a 2d vector that should be defined like this

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myvect = 
     { { 3, 2, 1, 4, 5 } 
     , { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
     , { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
     };
```

There's no intrinsic *compare* function provided for arbitrary `std::vector<>`'s, you have to implement one, and pass it to the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function.

Comment: ok, thanks. but how?
bool compare( ?, ? ) {...}

Comment: Actually, `std::vector` does provide an [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) that performs a lexicographical compare. I'm not sure if the question is asking about sorting by a single column or not.

Comment: The first row is sorted by < operator. The second and third row are sorted by the same mapping as the first row